# How to Modifiy the Right-Click Menu in Finder

Tags: shortcut-menu, contextual-menu

I have an error in my context menu for `*.txt` files:
[image: The Right-Click menu for NewFile.txt in Finder]

That entry for MacVim_8.0 is wrong. At one point I changed the name of the app, when for some reason I had both v7 and v8 installed. But now I'm on MacVim v9 and the app in the `Applications` folder is called simply `MacVim.app`.

When I click that entry in the context menu, the file gets opened properly in MacVim 9.0. So it's not getting the name from the `Applications` folder entry. It works, so it's not critical, but it's annoying to have the wrong name in the menu.

Any suggestions for where to go to fix it?

### Update: Answers to Questions in the Comments

- Which tool are you using to get the app names displayed there in the first place? –
  @nohillside

I have had that list in the context menu for a while, at least a couple of years. I don't have another Mac to compare with. Your question suggests to me that it's the result of setting that I changed or tool that I used. Whether that's a system tool or third party tool, I don't know.

- Does it get it right in the 'real' Open With menu? – @Tetsujin

Yes, the name is correct in the "real" Open With menu.

Comment: Which tool are you using to get the app names displayed there in the first place?

Comment: Does it get it right in the 'real' Open With menu?

Comment: You're using ServiceStation.  Wouldn't you just fix it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You're using ServiceStation. Wouldn't you just fix it there? – @Marc Wilson

Thanks. I had been seeing ServiceStation in the context menu and not used it in so long that I had forgotten what it is. When I opened it, I got this:
[image: ServiceStation screen showing erroneous name for MacVim]

Deleting the erroneous entry and adding a new one, selecting `MacVim.app` in `Applications`, fixed it.

Thanks.